# Slow network connection

Tags: networking, slow-connection

I'm working in a small company, up to 30 Internet connected devices. Since a few weeks we observe that our Internet connection is much slower than earlier. Browsing pages, downloading files is ~50-300 kbps. But when I download e.g. Ubuntu via torrent it is ~8000 kbps.

My ISP told me that our average network traffic is on the same level as always. And also asked me to do speed test on http://www.speedtest.net to the trusted server. The result was ~40Mb/s up- and down-link, but to the others it is ~4-5Mb/s.

Could you give me any hint how to investigate this problem?

Comment: The result was ~40Mb/s up- and down-link, but to the others it is ~4-5Mb/s.
--- what's that mean?

Comment: 40Mb/s to the trusted server. 4-5 Mb/s to the other servers.

Comment: Have you tried some popular high-speed sites like microsoft.com or oracle.com?

Comment: What's a trusted server? I've never seen that before on speedtest.net.

Comment: Trusted is the server which my ISP knows and they said it should work properly. It is in the other city on university.
How to test speed with microsoft.com/oracle.com?

Comment: you should still get reasonable speeds from other severs in your country/continent, etc... even if not optimal. 40Mbit down to 5Mbit is pretty bad. I'd discuss with your ISP.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8109 or just download anything from either site.

Comment: Transfer of this file vary between 80-110 KB/s...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43446/discussion-between-ryan-babchishin-and-blaz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of investigation is that one optical fiber patchcord was unclean what caused signal degradation. Now we have back 1Gbps into my company building, but we have to buy newer router becasue the one used now is 100Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

**If everything is fast between your site and your ISPs chosen speedtest.net server** and slow everywhere else on the Internet -

**Then there is nothing for you to troubleshoot.** This is your ISPs problem. You have just demonstrated that your configuration and link are performing properly.

Though you can try some more sites on your own that are normally very fast. I've always found microsoft.com and oracle.com to be excellent for this purpose. They both have large files you can download.

I hope your ISP is cooperative in finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where you are, but try
[speedtest](http://speedtest.btwholesale.com) from UK BT isp. it's not so nice from graphic point but test nice. I use it to check speed. Often has difference in speed but this is normal.
There could be couple reasons for slow connection. 
This slow down is continuously or only in specific times? Maybe this could be RAIN but it is difficult to find a source. Also maybe you have new user? who using company internet to download privet stuff?

Comment: I have changed router to a bit newer, but test results are similar in this test:
DL: 5.74 Mbps
UL: 14.11 Mbps
Ping Latency: 41.38 ms